# Fitting 3D points to a straight line

Tags: fitting

I have 3D data - a bunch of triples like `{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, ...}`, and I know they lie on a curve rather than a surface; in fact, I need a least squares fit of these points to a 3D straight line. That is, I am looking for six numbers `ax, bx, ay, by, az, bz` such that my points are as close as possible to the line `{ax*t + bx, ay*t + by, az*t + bz}`, with `t` running through reals. I could not find a way to do it in *Mathematica*. Does anybody know a way?

Comment: Please post your data

Comment: Orthogonal fitting is pretty much the only viable option in this case, but you'll have to set up `FindMinimum[]` yourself to do it, since this method is not built-in.

Comment: @JohnConorCosnett I have 1285 points, and unfortunately I don't know how to take a sensible small sample from them, sorry. You could take something like `Table[{.5 t + .1, 
  1.2 t - .3, -2.2 t + 1.2}+RandomReal[{-1,1},3], {t, 
  RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 100]}]`

Comment: @J.M. Would be very grateful if you could provide some details in an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it turns out, you don't need `FindMinimum[]` in the linear case of *total least squares*/*orthogonal distance* regression; all that is needed is a clever application of SVD:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            p = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 3]; (* point on true line *)
            (* direction cosines *)
            q = Normalize[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]];
            (* random points clustered near the line *)
            pts = Table[p + t q + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/10], 3],
                        {t, 0, 1, 1/90}];]

(* orthogonal fit *)
lin = InfiniteLine[Mean[pts], Flatten[Last[
                   SingularValueDecomposition[Standardize[pts, Mean, 1 &], 1]]]];

Legended[Graphics3D[{{Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], Brown], Point[pts]},
                     {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], ColorData[97, 1]], 
                      lin},
                     {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], ColorData[97, 3]], 
                      InfiniteLine[p, q]}}, Axes -> True], 
         LineLegend[{ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 3]},
                    {"orthogonal fit", "true line"}]]
```

[image: orthogonally-fitted line]

Comment: Is it easy to see that the best linear fit line must go through the mass center?

Comment: Also, it might be quite nontrivial to estimate errors for the comparison of various possible approaches...

Comment: [Here](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/103/6/j36sha.pdf) is a nice survey paper you might want to look at. If you want the residuals, you can use the usual method for finding the distance of a point to a line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful link.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the answer by [John Conor Cosnett](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36681/john-conor-cosnett) I came up with something:

```
data = Table[{.5, 1.2, -2.2} t + {.1, -.3, 1.2} + RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3],  
 {t, RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 100]}];
xyfit = FindFit[data[[All, {1, 2}]], axy x + bxy, {axy, bxy}, x]
xzfit = FindFit[data[[All, {1, 3}]], axz x + bxz, {axz, bxz}, x]
```

Seems to give good results,

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, axy x + bxy /. xyfit, axz x + bxz /. xzfit},
  {x, -10000, 10000}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListPointPlot3D[data],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

produces this:

[image]

Still I am in doubt since this approach somehow breaks symmetry, as it treats $x$ as an independent variable, with $y$ and $z$ as its functions. I somehow suspect this might introduce some bias, with errors not uniform wrt the variables. So I am leaving this unaccepted, maybe somebody can come up with something better.

Answer (score 2):

## Complete code for finding {ax, bx, ay, by, az, by} using your example data from your comment:

```
t = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 100];

points = pts = 
 Table[{.5 t + .1 + RandomReal[], 
 1.2 t - .3 + RandomReal[], -2.2 t + 1.2 + RandomReal[]}, {t, 
 RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 100]}];

 x = #[[1]] & /@ points; 
 y = #[[2]] & /@ points;
 z = #[[3]] & /@ points;


 Xdata = Thread[{t, x}];
 Ydata = Thread[{t, y}];
 Zdata = Thread[{t, z}];

 Clear[t]
  Join[
   FindFit[Xdata, ax*t + bx, {ax, bx}, t],
   FindFit[Ydata, ay*t + by, {ay, by}, t],
   FindFit[Zdata, az*t + bz, {az, bz}, t]
  ]
```

---

#### Contrived ExampleData:

```
f[t_] := {1 t + 2, 3*t + 4, 5*t + 6}

points = f /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1]
```

#### Split up data into 3 linear regressions:

> $x(t)=ax* t+ bx$
>
> $y(t)=ay* t+ by$
>
> $z(t)=az* t+ bz$

#### Make up $t$ data.

```
t = Range[0, 10, 0.1]
```

#### Extract x, y, z:

```
x = #[[1]] & /@ points;
y = #[[2]] & /@ points;
z = #[[3]] & /@ points;
```

#### Combine into {input, output} lists:

```
Xdata = Thread[{t, x}];
Ydata = Thread[{t, y}];
Zdata = Thread[{t, z}];
```

#### Use 3 separate `FindFit` operations:

```
Clear[t]
Join[
  FindFit[Xdata, ax*t + bx, {ax, bx}, t],
  FindFit[Ydata, ay*t + by, {ay, by}, t],
  FindFit[Zdata, az*t + bz, {az, bz}, t]
]
```

Comment: Hmmmm are you sure this is the right way? I mean, it somehow treats $x$, $y$ and $z$ coordinates as entirely unrelated separate random variables, is it OK?

Comment: They are related. They all are functions of the same independent variable t.

Comment: That's my trouble precisely, I just failed to formulate it well enough. What I have is a bunch of triples, I don't really know the corresponding `t`s for them. In your solution you use this information, but it must be presupposed to be hidden.

Comment: ok! I understand now! I will try to find a solution without knowledge of t!